# User control with on/off behavior in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I'm developing a simple Windows Phone 8 application and I need a user control to activate/deactivate a generic option. In other words, I'm looking for something link the Proxy field in this [image](http://atomaras.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/wp8_fiddler_capture_wifi_traffic.png).

I tried using System.Windows.Controls.Slider, but it allows only double value and I can't find a way to configure it to a on/off mode.
Which user control i should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are wanting the ToggleSwitch control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.toggleswitch

The toggle switch can be found as part of the later versions of the Phone SDK http://phone.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ToggleSwitch is what I was looking for! Latest version of the Phone SDK was already installed in my VS, but I could not use it because of the missed reference in the XAML file: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/78f6562e-f643-4ec3-8a6f-bd800d722f52/toggle-switch?forum=wpdevelop